# Python: how to use some kind of generic setter?

Tags: python

I've made this code:

```
if fc.get('field_photo_1'):
    pt.photo1 = fc.get('field_photo_1')
if fc.get('field_photo_2'):
    pt.photo2 = fc.get('field_photo_2')
if fc.get('field_photo_3'):
    pt.photo3 = fc.get('field_photo_3')
```

I'd like to optimize it to some kind of code like this:

```
update_field(photo1, 'field_photo_1'):
update_field(photo2, 'field_photo_2'):
update_field(photo3, 'field_photo_3'):
```

I just don't know how make kinddof a `setter` with index in python. How would you implement the `update_field()` function?

Comment: See getattr and setattr methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making an array of photos and then iterate strings with a for loop instead of trying to create such setter. It's easier to understand and doesn't do uncommon things with your class that other programmers might not expect.

```
class Pt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.photos = [None for i in range(3)]

pt = Pt()
for i in range(1,4)
    fieldString = 'field_photo_{0}'.format(i)
    if fc.get(fieldString):
        pt.photos[i] = fc.get(fieldString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr) function.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `setattr`, which accepts string attribute names.

Try this:

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    attrname = "photo_".format(x)
    setattr(pt, attrname, fc["field_".format(attrname)])
```

You should probably refactor your code though to use lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to set the pt attribute based on the passed parameter, setattr is the way to go.

```
def update_field(attribute, value):
    setattr(pt, attribute, value)
```

The other answers here assume that you are iterating through a preset number of photo attributes. If you are wanting a single set, then the above should work. If looking to set them all, Ben's or Ritave's answer might be more suitable.

Depending on the scope of the "pt" variable. You might have to do something like `setattr(self.pt, attribute, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `dict`:

```
photos = dict()
photos['photo1'] = fc.get('field_photo_1')
# etc...
```

Or more concisely:

```
photos = {photo: fc.get(photo) for photo in ('field_photo_1', 'field_photo_2', 'field_photo_3')}
```